# Parameter is invalid expection in Windows7 when trying to retrieve an image

Tags: c#, image, windows-7, stream

I am getting a parameter invalid exception while retrieving an image (error only occurs on Win7 but working fine in XP OS)

Here is my code

```
Image _image = null;
ImageConverter imgConverter = null;
_image = imgConverter.ConvertFrom(pItem.FrontImage) as System.Drawing.Image; //pItem.FrontImage is Byte[]
```

I have tried to use

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pItem.FrontImage);
ms.Write(pItem.FrontImage, 0, pItem.FrontImage.Length);
_image = Image.FromStream((Stream)ms);
```

but no use.

Can you please help me?

Complete error:

> System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
>   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
>   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream)

If not is there any other way to convert image from Byte[] without using FromStream.I have tried to save the Byte[] as Jpg with File.WriteAllBytes but no use   (Image is showing as corrupted).

Comment: Post the exact exception.

Comment: Your code will not compile.

Comment: Also we would need to know what pItem is?

Comment: The `ArgumentException` has a [ParamName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.argumentexception.paramname.aspx) property that holds the name of the parameter.